# Terraform iterate over list in map

Tags: terraform, nested-loops

i'm working with terraform, and I have configuration like this:

```
locals  {
  clusters {
    "cluster1" = {
      instance_type = "t2.large"
      vms = ["vm1", "vm2", "vm3"]
      cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
    }
    "cluster2" = {
      instance_type = "t2.large"
      vms = ["vm1", "vm2", "vm3"]
      cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to deploy 3 virtual machines per cluster.

```
resource "aws_instance" "cluster_vms" {
  for_each = local.clusters
  ami = local.amis.ubuntu2204
  instance_type = each.value.instance_type
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnets["${each.key}"].id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.generic_sg.id]
  key_name = "my_pair"
}
```

This will create only 2 vms as there are 2 clusters.  I need to be able to deploy 6 virtual machines and I did not find a way how to create virtual machines named as:

`["cluster1_vm1", "cluster2_vm1", "cluster1_vm2", .... ]`   Is this possible? Or the better question is, how to approach to this?

Comment: I don't think the local variable is correct, so please correct that first.

Comment: sorry, it was jut an typo, I was typing it by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a new `local` and using the [flatten](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten) function :

```hcl
locals {
  clusters = {
    "cluster1" = {
      instance_type = "t2.large"
      vms           = ["vm1", "vm2", "vm3"]
      cidr_block    = "10.0.0.0/24"
    }
    "cluster2" = {
      instance_type = "t2.large"
      vms           = ["vm1", "vm2", "vm3"]
      cidr_block    = "10.0.0.0/24"
    }
  }
  cluster_vm_names = flatten([
    for cluster, cluster_data in local.clusters : [
      for vm in cluster_data.vms : {
        name          = "${cluster}_${vm}"
        instance_type = cluster_data.instance_type
        cidr_block    = cluster_data.cidr_block
      }
    ]
  ])
}



resource "aws_instance" "cluster_vms" {
  for_each = {
    for entry in local.cluster_vm_names : entry.name => entry
  }
  ami                    = local.amis.ubuntu2204
  instance_type          = each.value.instance_type
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.public_subnets["${each.key}"].id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.generic_sg.id]
  key_name               = "my_pair"
}

}
```

I advise you read some doc about [for](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) : this will help you a lot ;)

Comment: thanks, I somehow missed that I can nest for loops to do this. I need to read slower before asking.... thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the local variable to give you the cluster & VM combinations. See docs [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten):

```
locals {
  cluster_vms_flat = flatten([
    for cluster_name, cluster in local.clusters : [
      for vm in cluster.vms : {
        cluster_name   = cluster_name
        instance_type  = cluster.instance_type
        vm_name        = vm
        cidr_block     = cluster.cidr_block
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

This would give you the following list of maps, which you can use to construct your resource names using `'${cluster_name}_${vm_name}'`:

```json
[
  {
    "cluster_name" = "cluster1"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
    "vm_name" = "vm1"
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
  },
  {
    "cluster_name" = "cluster1"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
    "vm_name" = "vm2"
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
  },
  {
    "cluster_name" = "cluster1"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
    "vm_name" = "vm3"
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
  },
  {
    "cluster_name" = "cluster2"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
    "vm_name" = "vm1"
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
  },
  {
    "cluster_name" = "cluster2"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
    "vm_name" = "vm2"
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
  },
  {
    "cluster_name" = "cluster2"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
    "vm_name" = "vm3"
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
  },
...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like the following

```
vms2 = merge([for cluster_name, cluster in local.clusters : {
    for vm in cluster.vms : "${cluster_name}-${vm}" => {
      instance_type = cluster.instance_type
      cidr_block    = cluster.cidr_block
  } }]...)
```

Which will output, using the values from your example:

```
{
  "cluster1-vm1" = {
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
  }
  "cluster1-vm2" = {
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
  }
  "cluster1-vm3" = {
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
  }
  "cluster2-vm1" = {
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
  }
  "cluster2-vm2" = {
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
  }
  "cluster2-vm3" = {
    "cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/24"
    "instance_type" = "t2.large"
  }
}
```

Then, from this it would be trivial to create the VMs using a `for_each`.

What I did was, first of all create a list of objects, then merging it using the `merge` function together with the ellipsis operator `...`.